# How to use library SoX with Python in Windows?

Tags: dll, sox, libsox

As you know much speech processing/recognition tools on the literature use SoX(Sound Exchange) library. However, based on the original documentation sox is not supported in Windows by https://pysox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. As we clone the repositories from the github since many of them are implemented in Linux, it is an issue for Windows user. Linux user can  directly install and use in Python by

```py
pip install sox // Installing
import sox
```

However, in Windows there is need for installing original source from https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/ and there is an issue with how to connect it with the Python so that by import it can be used.

I have tried to use `soxbindings` library to link between the Sox and python importing in Windows, but I can't. SoX version sox-14-4-2 original source has the following .dll files
and executable file sox.exe.

```
libflac-8.dll
libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dd
libgomp-1.dll
libid3tag-0.dll
libogg-0.dll
libpng16-16.dll
libsox-3.dll
libssp-0.dll
libvorbis-0.dll
libvorbisenc-2.dll
libvorbisfile-3.dll
libwavpack-1.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
```

How can I construct a link between soure Sox and python?